# Multi image classes classification using CNN Keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to classify 100 images.
These images are belong to 12 classes.
I have a csv file that contain the image ID (the ID is the image file name) and the image classes.
How I can use and divide the classes from the csv file into train and test.
I mean when I split the data into train and test, how I can divide the 100 pictures and their classes from the csv file to train and test, then feed them to the model.
I use python and Keras library.

```
import os
import cv2
from keras.layers import Input,Dense,Flatten,Dropout,merge,Reshape,Conv3D,MaxPooling3D,UpSampling3D,Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model,Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta, RMSprop,SGD,Adam
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import numpy.random as rng
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import nibabel as nib #reading MR images
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import math
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
files = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/im_id/*')
files[0]
len(files)
images = []
for f in range(len(files)):
  a = nib.load(files[f])
  a = a.get_data()
  images.append(a)
print(a.shape)
images = np.asarray(images)
print(images.shape)
labeles = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My 
Drive/img_id.csv')
print(labeles)
class_names = labeles["Class"]
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(110, 110, 110, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Comment: Please post a code for what you have done so far.

Comment: I have no idea about how to split them. I only made the model and load the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `tf.data.Dataset`, which is an abstraction that represents a sequence of elements, in which each element consists of one or more components. In other words, it's a generator in python.

I don't know your data, so I can't help you properly. The best I can do is to give you a gist of how to do it and to share some links.

In brief, you need to read your `csv` file, I suggest using `pandas`, and the images' path. Now, you can split them using `NumPy`, for example, you can shuffle your data and then get the first 10% of values in the array for testing and the rest for training.

Next, you need to use the `tf.data` API to generate the datasets. The method `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` do the job for you. You just need to pass the `NumPy` arrays as parameters and get the generators to pass to your `Keras` pipeline. You must do that to your training and testing arrays.

I have a pipeline to do that [here](https://github.com/paaatcha/jedy_tf1x/blob/master/utils/loader.py). Feel free to use it. You can also check the manual [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)

Comment: Thanks so much. My data are mri images in 3D.

Comment: It's the same pipeline, you just need to change the way you load the data from the disk. the tensor slices will work in the same way.